# Is there an elegant way in Scala to define an asynchronous API based on a synchronous one?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I suspect the answer is NO, but thought I would ask anyway.

Given something like

```
trait foo {
  def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int
}
```

Is there some Scala magic I can do to produce, or implicitly define

```
trait fooAsync {
  def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Future[Int]
}
```

or do I just have to brute force it, and define fooAsync explicitly? Would Scala macros help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the synchronous api is defined by you, you could write the following:

```
trait Foo {
  type Response[A]

  def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Response[Int]
  def diff(a: Int, b: Int): Response[Int]
  /* ... */
}

trait SyncFoo extends Foo {
  type Response[A] = A
}

trait AsyncFoo extends Foo {
  type Response[A] = Future[A]
}
```

If you do not really need the asynchronous interface, then you could just wrap all calls to your synchronous api in `Future { ... }`.